# OpenApi 3 with Kotlin does not generates validation

Tags: kotlin, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate requests with OpenApi generator, but all constraints like min, minvalue, maxlength etc are ignored. Example:

```
data class SomeClassNameGen (

        @JsonProperty("queryText") val queryText: kotlin.String,

        @JsonProperty("test") val test: kotlin.Int? = null
}
```

code from openapi.yaml

```
SomeClassName:
  title: desc
  description: desc
  type: desc
  properties:
    test:
      type: integer
      minimum: 1
      maximum: 20
    queryText:
      description: Текст запроса
      type: string
      minLength: 10,
      exclusiveMaximum: true
  required:
    - queryText
```

Comment: Likely these validations are not yet supported in the generator. Please open an issue via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new/ with the details so the openapi-generator community can help you out.